# TTIMESTAMP shows different date in SQL IDE and in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, postgresql

I connected to the same remote databases on SQL IDE (datagrip) and jupyter notebook. I ran the same query like `select id, registered_date from table where id = '12345'`

I got different `registered_date` in IDE and in Jupyter notebook. The IDE shows `2021-12-31 20:09:00.000000` and the jupyter notebook shows `2022-01-01 09:09:00+13:00`

It looks like jupyter notebook is influenced by some timestamp settings?

I'm using postgresql.

Comment: Yep.  Python is showing you the local time.  Your Jupyter server must be in New Zealand.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes that's right. Ok so I'll just need to find a way to convert local to UTC time

Comment: This is a presentation issue. SQL IDE and Jupyter notebook *present* (i.e. convert a timestamp to formatted text) the result differently. Try `select id, to_char(registered_date, 'YY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS OF') from table where id = '12345'` and you will get the same result from both.

Answer (score 0):

From @Stefanov.sm comment on the original post, this solved the problem:

```
select 
  id, 
  to_char(registered_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`)
from table where id = '12345'
```